# Perl XML::Twig Copying without children

Tags: perl, xml-twig

Is it possible to use somthing like

```
my $nodeCopy = $node->copy();
```

without copying the children? I can't find anything on the [page on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) about it. But maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a way. Going to leave it here if ever somebody else looks for something similar. All you have to do is use `cut_children`.
I did it like this:

```
my $nodeCopy = $node->copy();       #copy the node
$nodeCopy->paste('before', $node);  #paste the node
$node->cut_children();             #remove children from the original node
```

Comment: Nice.  Yes, leave it, that's good. You can also accept your own answer, which I think is a good idea here.

Comment: It will take another couple of hours before they can accept their answer, though.